# Generate multiple html inputs with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, input

I have a `form` which the user will write a `number (int)` he wants, and then there's a `button` besides this `textbox` that must read the `value` written on the `input` and create the exact numbers of `textboxes` which the user had written in a `modal`.

This is what I've been trying so far, but I can't get any kind of result.

```
<input id="my_input" name="test1"  type="text" value="" >

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="add_input()" id="add_input1"  name="" type="submit">GO</button>

 <script>
function add_inputs()
{
    n = $('#my_input').val();
    console.log(n);

    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++);
        console.log(i);

    $("#rolonum_" + i).html('<span>Item 1</span><input id="rolo_add' + i + '" name="addposition"  type="text" value="" required/>');
}

</script>
```

Comment: `n` is a string right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems with your code:

1. You have defined the JS function as "add_inputs" but have tied onclick function to "add_input" (note the missing "s").
2. In the function "add_inputs" you have put a semicolon just after the "for" clause, effectively making it useless because there is no code to execute for the iterations of the loop
3. You need to place your dynamically generated input-boxes somewhere on the DOM. These could be inside the body or some other element. 
   You have tried to insert them in an element with an id ("#rolonum_" + i), which is wrong because such an element DOES NOT exist.

The correct code would be:

```js
function add_inputboxes() {
  n = $('#my_input').val();
  if (n < 1)
    alert("ERROR: Enter a positive number");
  else {
    $("#rolonum").html('');
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      $("#rolonum").append('<p><span>Item ' + i + ' </span><input id="rolo_add' + i + '" name="addposition"  type="text" value="" required/></p>');
    }
  }
}

//Yet Another way to do the same thing
 jQuery('#add_input2').click(add_inputboxes);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my_input" name="test1" type="text" value="">

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="add_input1" name="" type="button" onclick="add_inputboxes()">GO</button>

<!-- Yet Another button to do the same thing -->
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="add_input2" name="" type="button">Create Inputs</button>


<p>The Buttons go in #rolonum :</p>
<div id="rolonum"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```js
  function add_inputs() {
    n = $('#my_input').val();
    $("#rolonum").html('');
    for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      $("#rolonum").append('<span>Item ' + i + ' </span><input id="rolo_add' + i + '" name="addposition"  type="text" value="" required/><br>');

    }

  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my_input" name="test1" type="text" value="">

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="add_inputs()" id="add_input1" name="" type="button">GO</button>

<div id="rolonum">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a few things wrong there. You have to have a place to put the elements when you generate them. Also fixed a couple mismatched selectors (your onclick function name didn't match the actual function name), and replaced the inline onclick with something more appropriate. Try this...

```js
var btn = $("#add_input1");
btn.on('click',function() {
 var n = $("#my_input").val();
  console.log(n);
  
  for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  $("#inputs").append('<span>Item '+i+'</span><input id="rolo_add'+i+'" name="addposition"  type="text" value="" required/><br/>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="my_input" name="test1"  type="text" value="" >

<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="add_input1"  name="" type="submit">GO</button>

<div id="inputs"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
        for(var i = 1; i < n; i++);
```

It's a useless statement. The `;` at the end basically says "This is a loop that does nothing". The loop will run, it'll increment `i`, but at the end, that's **ALL** it does. There's no body, so you're not executing anything but the `i++`.

Maybe you wanted something more like

```
for (...) {
   console.log(i);
   $('#rolonum_"+i).etc....
}
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `type="submit"` which will submit the page and your function will not be called. Change type to button like `type="button"`

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="add_input()" id="add_input1"  name="" type="button">GO</button>
```

Also modify your function as pointed by Marc B

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#add_input1").on("click",function(){

        n = $('#my_input').val();

        for(var i = 1; i <=n; i++) {

            $("body").append('<span>Item'+ i + ' : </span><input id=rolo_add'+i+' name=addposition type=text value="" required/><br>');

        }
    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        
    </head>
    <body> 
        
        <input id="my_input" name="test1"  type="text" value="" >
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="add_input1"  name="" type="submit">GO</button>
        <br><br>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>  
            
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#add_input1").on("click",function(){

                n = $('#my_input').val();

                for(var i = 1; i <=n; i++) {

                    $("body").append('<span>Item'+ i + ' : </span><input id=rolo_add'+i+' name=addposition type=text value="" required/><br>');

                }
                console.log(i-1);
            })
        })
        
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```